# How to open RECORD.alM file from mimic2db in Cygwin?

Tags: annotations, cygwin

I try to open annotation file from mimic2 db for patient a40017 that called a40017.alM.
I have this link for the data: http://www.physionet.org/pn5/mimic2db/a40017/
and I don't find the exact command in Cygwin that export the file to csv or text.

I try to use this command: 
rdann -r mimic2db/a40017/a40017 -f 0 -t 216647.728  -a alM -v >annotations.txt
but I got an empty file

Is anyone know how can I do that?

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: Is rdann a cygwin program ?

Answer (score 0):

Anwering myself. Rdann is a mingw32/64 program

https://physionet.org/physiotools/binaries/windows/

If you are in the same directory of the program and it is not in the PATH you need to run:

```
./rdann -r mimic2db/a40017/a40017 -f 0 -t 216647.728 -a alM -v
```

or

```
/<fullpath>/rdann ...
```